# double semicolon in dangling else in php

Tags: php, parsing, if-statement

i have started learning php and i saw a piece of code in php documentations that was bug reported but in the report page said that was not a bug.
the code is :

```
$bar = 'bar';
$foo = 'foo';

if (isset($bar)):
   if (isset($foo)) echo "Both are set.";
elseif (isset($foo)):
   echo "Only 'foo' is set.";
else:
   echo "Only 'bar' is set.";
endif;
```

if we put the nested if code in curly braces again that error is happening.

```
if (isset($bar)) :
    if (isset($foo)) {  
           echo "Both are set.";
    }
elseif (isset($foo)) :
       echo "Only 'foo' is set.";
else :
       echo "No one is set.";
endif;
```

the above code raise an error unexpected ":" and the reason of report page said this it is not a bug it was the mixed structure used in above code and php does not allowed and i accepted that but what makes this code go wrong.
but why if we add another semicolon at the end of nested if statement it works perfectly.
or why if we add else statement at the end of nested if statement error will gone.
something like this :

```
if (isset($bar)) :
    if (isset($foo)) {  
           echo "Both are set.";
    } else {
            echo "this is else";
    }
elseif (isset($foo)) :
       echo "Only 'foo' is set.";
else :
       echo "No one is set.";
endif;
```

i will appreciate if anyone help i know this mixed structure is really bad but understanding the problem will help to prevent another mistakes.
thanks a lot;

Comment: Would you mind adding a link to the page you're talking about?

Comment: I think you should **not** mix writing `if` statements in curly braces and the alternative structure - that's how the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) states it

Comment: The problem is it would read like the `elseif` with the colon was actually part  of the second `if` with curly bracket, instead of part of the first `if` statement with the colon notation. Your best bet to avoid these sort of problems are only nest one style of control structures.

Comment: From the documentation Nico linked: **Note:
Mixing syntaxes in the same control block is not supported.**

Comment: yes absolutely here is the link of the bug
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75138,

Comment: as i said in my question above i know mixed structure is not allowed but if it is not allowed why another semicolon or else statement at the end of nested if statement fix the problem?
if it is not allowed it should not work at all.
what makes it works correctly?

Comment: Trying to reason about the behaviour that's explicitly "not allowed" (and frankly, was a bizarre design choice in the first place - two syntaxes for the same thing???) is probably not going to yield many useful answers.  FWIW, I'm still reading through that bug report, though.

Comment: But now that I have read through it, I'm inclined to agree with the PHP devs (for once) - this doesn't seem to be a bug, but simply a result of how the grammar is defined.

Comment: *"i have started learning php"* -- stay away from the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). It is useful (not needed but useful) in templates but it is too verbose to be useful in the code. Always use curly braces (even when there is only one statement they enclose) and the appropriate indentation (for readability) and you won't have troubles with this issue again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this:

```
if (cond):
    if (cond) stuff();
elseif (cond):
    stuff();
else:
    stuff();
endif;
```

is really an instance of the [*dangling-else*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) problem - does the `elseif` belong to the "inner" or the "outer" `if` in an whitespace-insensitive language?

PHP [chooses to parse](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/11-statements.md#grammar-if-statement) it as this:<sup>1</sup>

```
if (cond):
    if (cond)
        stuff();
    elseif (cond):
        stuff();
    else:
        stuff();
    endif;
```

which mixes the two syntaxes, which is "[not supported](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)".

So one might be inclined to say that this is a bug (which is not the conclusion of the related [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75138)) - the spec states:

> An `else` clause is associated with the lexically nearest preceding `if` or `elseif` that is permitted by the syntax.

Assuming that this also applies to `elseif` clauses, then one might say that the parser should associate our `elseif` with our outer `if`, as nothing else is permitted.

---

The problem is mitigated by anything which causes the above parse not to be possible.  To take the simplest example from that bug report:

```
if (cond):
    if (cond) stuff();
    ;                   // <<<<
elseif (cond):
    stuff();
else:
    stuff();
endif;
```

The extra semicolon means that the `elseif` can't be interpreted as part of the inner `if`/`elseif`/`if` chain.

---

<sub>1. In this particular code snippet, I'm pretending that whitespace is important.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer this question is posted in php documentation it is not bad to post this answer to that page

Comment: @Mahdi - Feel free to do so :)  (Though if so, please ensure there's a link back to here!)

Comment: Can you please explain why the else statement fix problem it doesn't have semi colon ???

Comment: @Mahdi - It's the same logic, really.  You can't have `if`/`else`/`elseif`.  So the `elseif` must be associated with the outer `if`.

Comment: Actually, on second thoughts, maybe this **is** a bug.  The language spec states that clauses should be associated with the nearest `if` that is permitted.  Given that mixed syntax is **not** permitted, I'd be inclined to say that the parser should associate our `elseif` with the **outer** `if`.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Im completely confused ; i understand your first answer that the parser think elseif belong to the nested if but now you think this is a bug and im confusing???!!

Comment: @mahdi: don't get hung up on what I think, it's not important :)  Regardless of whether it is actually a bug, the PHP team think it's not a bug, so the behaviour is what it is.